# Issue extract clob by Datastage

Tags: xml, oracle, clob, datastage

I using Oracle Connector to load CLOB column from Oracle table. I have set LongVarchar type for column of Oracle Connector. When I click view data and get error message. Can anyone can help me solve this? Thanks

"Oracle_Connector_0,0: The OCI function OraOCILobRead2 returned status -1. Error code: 24806, Error message: ORA-24806: LOB form mismatch. 
(CC_OraBigBufferHandler::callbackGetDataFromOCILobLocator, file CC_OraBigBufferHandler.cpp, line 5,810)[image]"

Comment: I did follow below suggestions but still not solving the proble http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683420

Answer (score 0):

If your job has a length assigned for the LongVarChar column receiving CLOB data, then delete the length (leave the field completely blank)

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the column definitions from DDL. Sometimes if you are not defining the variable in way that are not compatible with source, you get these error. Refere to: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21670994

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you are using the correct SQL type on Datastage. It should be `LongVarChar` with other parameters unset. [Ref1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.3?topic=types-data-type-mappings-from-oracle-infosphere-datastage)

Second, change the `Array size` property of the first Oracle stage (`Oracle_Connection_0`) from 2000 to 1. [Ref2](http://www.dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?t=149001)

Finally, remeber that the `View data` for `CLOB` columns will always fail. So, in order to test if it's working you will need to run the full job, or create a copy of it and then send the output to a sequential file.